# How to display the response from an HTTPHandler on the cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a cshtml page that has a form which sends data to an HTTPHandler. If I run into some kind of error I want to respond with an error message and display it in the same cshtml page. How can I do this? 
Here is my handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var mode = context.Request.Form["mode"];
    var title = context.Request.Form["postTitle"];
    var content = context.Request.Form["postContent"];
    var slug = context.Request.Form["postSlug"];
    var id = context.Request.Form["postId"];
    var datePublished = context.Request.Form["postDatePublished"];

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(slug))
    {
        slug = CreateSlug(title);
    }

    if (mode == "edit")
    {
        EditPost(Convert.ToInt32(id), title, content, slug, datePublished, 1);
    }
    else if (mode == "new")
    {
        CreatePost(title, content, slug, datePublished, 1);
    }

    context.Response.Redirect("~/admin/post/");
}

private static void CreatePost(string title, string content, 
    string slug, string datePublished, int authorId)
{
    var result = PostRepository.Get(slug);
    DateTime? published = null;

    if (result != null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(409, "Slug is already in use.");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(datePublished))
    {
        published = DateTime.Parse(datePublished);
    }

    PostRepository.Add(title, content, slug, published, authorId);
}

private static void EditPost(int id, string title, string content,
    string slug, string datePublished, int authorId)
{
    var result = PostRepository.Get(id);
    DateTime? published = null;

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Post does not exist.");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(datePublished))
    {
        published = DateTime.Parse(datePublished);
    }

    PostRepository.Edit(id, title, content, slug, published, authorId);
}

private static string CreateSlug(string title)
{
    title = title.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" ", "-");
    title = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^0-9a-z-]", string.Empty);

    return title;
}
```

And here is the form in the cshtml file

```
var post = Post.Current;

<div>
    <form name="post" method="post" action="~/admin/post.ashx">
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="@mode" />
        <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="@post.Id" />
        <p>Title: <input type="text" name="postTitle" value="@post.Title" /></p>
        <p>Content: <textarea name="postContent">@post.Content</textarea></p>
        <p>Slug: <input type="text" name="postSlug" value="@post.Slug" /></p>
        <p>Date Published: <input type="text" name="postDatePublished" value="@post.DatePublished" /></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="postSubmit" value="Submit" /></p>

    </form>
</div>
```

For example: Right now I'm throwing an exception if the post slug already exists. How would I send an error message that says "Slug is already in use" and then display it on the cshtml page preferably right on top of the form? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using an HTTPHandler and not a regular Controller/Action? When using a regular Controller/Action, you can use `TempData` in which you can stick some error messages and show them when redirecting back to the age with the Form.

Comment: @BFree I'm not familiar with Controller/Action. I guess they are part of the MVC framework. I'm using the simple ASP.NET Webpages.

Comment: Suggest you *do* move to Razor MVC web application programming. It can support this type of feature in a trivial way. That choice may of course be out of your control, but I can only advise :)